# Close all dropdowns $root event

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a special case in my UI where I need to close all opened b-bropdown components (including b-nav-item-dropdown).

I haven't found how to do so in a similar way as b-tooltip offers.

```
this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::tooltip');
```

Something like this would be perfect:

```
this.$root.$emit('bv::close::dropdown');
```

At this point I can accept any hackish answer as long as it works as intended. Should I use mixins? If so, how to do that cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

The guys at bootstrap-vue offered an undocumented way to do the same with another event:

```
this.$root.$emit('bv::link::clicked');
```

Comment: This seems to not work anymore using bootstrap-vue 2.0.0-rc.15, will try rc-19

Answer (score -1):

You can do this on component instance

```
<b-dropdown ref="foo"></b-dropdown>


this.$refs.foo.hide();
```

Comment: The intention is to close all dropdowns from all components, therefore I do not have a $ref to each of them.